# Parsing a text file into a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, pandas

I have a `.txt` file that looks like this:

```
SHT1 E:   T1:30.45°C    H1:59.14 %RH
SHT2 S:   T2:29.93°C    H2:67.38 %RH

SHT1 E:   T1:30.49°C    H1:58.87 %RH
SHT2 S:   T2:29.94°C    H2:67.22 %RH

SHT1 E:   T1:30.53°C    H1:58.69 %RH
SHT2 S:   T2:29.95°C    H2:67.22 %RH
```

I want to have a `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
      T1     H1     T2     H2
0  30.45  59.14  29.93  67.38
1  30.49  58.87  29.94  67.22
2  30.53  58.69  29.95  67.22
```

I parse this by:

1. Reading up the text file line by line
2. Parsing the lines e.g. matching only the parts with `T1, T2, H1, and H2`, splitting by `:`, and removing `°C` and `%RH`
3. The above produces a list of lists each having *two* items
4. I flatten the list of lists
5. Just to chop it up into a list of four-item lists
6. Dump that to a `df`
7. Write to an Excel file

Here's the code:

```py
import itertools

import pandas as pd


def read_lines(file_object) -> list:
    return [
        parse_line(line) for line in file_object.readlines() if line.strip()
    ]


def parse_line(line: str) -> list:
    return [
        i.split(":")[-1].replace("°C", "").replace("%RH", "")
        for i in line.strip().split()
        if i.startswith(("T1", "T2", "H1", "H2"))
    ]


def flatten(parsed_lines: list) -> list:
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(parsed_lines))


def cut_into_pieces(flattened_lines: list, piece_size: int = 4) -> list:
    return [
        flattened_lines[i:i + piece_size] for i
        in range(0, len(flattened_lines), piece_size)
    ]


with open("your_text_data.txt") as data:
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        cut_into_pieces(flatten(read_lines(data))),
        columns=["T1", "H1", "T2", "H2"],
    )
    print(df)
    df.to_excel("your_table.xlsx", index=False)
```

This works and I get what I want *but* I feel like points `3, 4, and 5` are a bit of redundant work, especially creating a list of list just to flatten it and then chop it up again.

---

#### Question:

*How could I simplify the whole parsing process? Or maybe most of the heavy-lifting can be done with `pandas` alone?*

Also, any other feedback is more than welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I know this is a very liberal interpretation of a code review since it suggests an entirely different approach. I still thought it might provide a useful perspective when thinking about such problems in the future and reducing coding effort.

I would suggest the following approach using [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to extract all the numbers that match the format "12.34".

```
import re
import pandas as pd

with open("your_text_data.txt") as data_file:
    data_list = re.findall(r"\d\d\.\d\d", data_file.read())

result = [data_list[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, len(data_list), 4)]

df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=["T1", "H1", "T2", "H2"])
print(df)
df.to_excel("your_table.xlsx", index=False)
```

This will of course only work for the current data format you provided. The code will need to be adjusted if the format of your data changes. For example: If relevant numbers may contain a varying number of digits, you might use the regex `"\d+\.\d+"` to match all numbers that contain at least one digit on either side of the decimal point.

Also please note the use of the context manager `with open(...) as x:`. Only code that accesses the object needs to and should be part of the managed context.

Comment: I absolutely don't mind that you've offered a new approach. I totally forgot about regex, I was so much into those lists of lists. This is short, simple, and does the job. Nice! Thank you for your time and insight.

Comment: PS. You've got your imports the other way round. `re` should be first and then `pandas`.

Comment: You're right, I fixed the import order!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy.loadtxt()` to read the data and `numpy.reshape()` to get the shape you want. The default is to split on whitespace and dtype of float.  `usecols` are the columns we want. `conveters` is a dict mapping column nos. to functions to convert the column data; here they chop of the unwanted text. The `.shape()` converts the resulting numpy array from two columns to four columns (the -1 lets numpy calculate the number of rows).

```
src.seek(0)
data = np.loadtxt(src,
                  usecols=(2, 3), 
                  converters={2:lambda s:s[3:-2], 3:lambda s:s[3:]}
                 ).reshape(-1, 4)
```

Then just load it in a dataframe and name the columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns='T1 H1 T2 H2'.split())
df
```

Output:

```
       T1      H1      T2      H2
0   30.45   59.14   29.93   67.38
1   30.49   58.87   29.94   67.22
2   30.53   58.69   29.95   67.22
```